# How to Concatenate the strings in each loop using jquery

Tags: jquery, concatenation, each

I want to concatenate the html of images using jquery in each loop. Here is my code which is not working. I am getting url of images from li attributes and then setting image tag for each url. I am able to get the url successfully but can't concatenate the image tags for each li.  need assistance

```
$('.nav li').each(function(){
        var img_link = $(this).attr('data-menu');
        var img_html = '<img src="'+img_link+'">';
        // here I have to concatenate the img_html in gethtml variable and then I will put it in a div.                 
        });
        $('.main-img').html(gethtml);
```

Comment: you should research jQuery `append` http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do `gethtml += '<img src="'+img_link+'">';` and initialise `gethtml` as `''` outside the loop:

```
var gethtml ='';
$('.nav li').each(function(){
    var img_link = $(this).attr('data-menu');
    gethtml += '<img src="'+img_link+'">';
});
$('.main-img').html(gethtml);
```

Comment: @Rizwi you can tick mark the answer if that was helpful to you

Comment: @rizwi you need to initialize the `gethtml` outside of the loop because of scope. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Slow internet got me lacking. :P

Comment: @TylerFowle it's outside

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal just further explaining _why_ you have to do that

Answer (score 3):

Try out this code:

```
let gethtml = '';
$('.nav li').each(function() {
    var img_link = $(this).attr('data-menu');
    var img_html = '<img src="'+img_link+'">';
    gethtml += img_html + ', ';                
});

$('.main-img').html(gethtml);
```

It will concatenate the `gethtml` variable with the `img_html` separated by *commas*.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for doing that like below:

```
$('.nav li').each(function () {        
    $('.main-img').append($(document.createElement('img')).attr("src", $(this).attr('data-menu')));
});
```